# How do you deselect MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

```
USE MyDatabase;
```

How do I `UNUSE MyDatabase` or `DESELECT MyDatabase` so I can use `SHOW DATABASES` again? What is the opposite of `USE`?

Comment: `show databases` shows all the databases regardless of whether you have selected one. Be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is no `UNUSE`. You just select another database and `USE` it.

Comment: But what if I don't want to use any database? Like if I just run `mysql -u <whatever>` is there any way to get back to that state?

Comment: @ohhh Anything you're going to do to a database, use it first. Anything you're not going to do to a database then it does not matter what you currently have selected since you're not doing anything with it, you'll never really need to "deselect" a database.

Comment: @cossacksman it is not true. If you write:
use somedb
Now you are unable to write:
drop database somedb

Answer (score 39):

Bruce Daniels presented an answer at https://web.archive.org/web/20160130220207/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/use.html.

It goes like:

```
CREATE DATABASE foofoofooweird;
USE foofoofooweird;
DROP DATABASE foofoofooweird;
```

Et voila, no database is in use.

To be clear, the hack is to CREATE, USE, then DROP (delete) a temporary placeholder database.
It is NOT advocating dropping (deleting) any database you actually use!

All credits to Bruce Daniels!

Comment: Find out the database currently in use with `SELECT database();`.

Comment: Lol, kind of hacky, but I guess it is a clever workaround.

Comment: I'm not qualified to use hacks employing DROP.

Answer (score 1):

As said in other answers, you simply can switch to another database, but if you just want to use none of the databases you can quit from mysql session and start it again.

```
\q

mysql -u username -p password
```

I don't see clear reason to do this, but it answers the question.

Comment: Yep, appending `exit;` to the end is what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cmd can't make "unuse" function, if you want to change between databases, just use the `USE DATABASENAME;` command.

Comment: The same solution was already proposed in another answer and that answer was accepted.

Answer (score -1):

There is no command UNUSE as USE db_name,
but instead you can use the same USE statement but with the replacing db name.
Suppose i am now working in world db and want to chanage to employee
intially i have entered USE world  now i will simply enter use employees