# Leave a MariaDB database without quitting

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In a MariaDB console (Windows command window), is there a way to leave a database without quitting?  (and without going to another database)  I tried `use NULL;` but that just looks for a database named "null".

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need to do this? `USE` doesn't use any resources AFAIK.

Comment: It's not important.  I was about to drop the database that I was in, and it didn't seem right that I should have to switch to another arbitrary database in order to do that.  It seems like there should be a way to get back to (none), as if I had just logged in.  If there isn't, then I guess that's the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you deselect MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895328/how-do-you-deselect-mysql-database)

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, but the answer seems to be 'no'. The suggested workaround of creating a dummy database (perhaps with a short, memorable name) seems sensible. Incidentally, I suspect that if you could do this, then you could probably drop the db without leaving it, as that action would simply return you to the same place

Comment: For what you want to do , i.e  dropping database you're currently, "USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA" could be in order. this one is virtual, you can't drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USE` command is a non standard SQL extension (also supported in SQL server) and selects a default name space (database name).

Without a default namespace (database) name you need to specify the database in your SQL syntax: e.g. `SELECT a FROM myschema.t1`.

There is no command to unset the default database, since it doesn't make any sense. Either you want to use a default name space, or you don't want. There is also no way to unset the default database via client API, both `COM_SELECT_DB` and `COM_CHANGE_USER` protocol commands doesn't change the default database if you pass a NULL parameter.

However client programs should always be aware if the default database changes or drops to avoid inconsistency and errors.
This can be achieved e.g. by executing the statement `SELECT DATABASE()` (this is what the mysql command line client is doing) or in recent MySQL and MariaDB versions by analyzing the [session track info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ok_packet/#session-state-info) which is part of the OK packet sent from server to the client.

Example for command line client:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create schema x;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use x;
Database changed
MariaDB [x]> drop schema x;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I had assumed that I wouldn't be able to drop a database while my client had a connection to it, so I didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to "un-use" in SQL. There is not such a command in SQL. That means that you are not allowed to come back to the "none" state. instead you can keep using "use" and change to another DB. Remember that DB's are not folders and you can create a DB while using any other DB.